# format from tuple to float in python?

Tags: python

```
def tong_thoigian (self,kr,uid,ids,context={}):
    obj=self.browse(kr,uid,ids,context=context)[0]
    kr.execute('''select name,giolam from x_giolam where name=%s'''%(obj.ma_luong))
    kq=kr.fetchall()
    tong=0.00000
    for i in kq:
          tong+=kq[1]                      
    self.write(kr,uid,ids,{'tonggiolam':tong},context=context)
```

the error is:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'float' and 'tuple'
```

I think you don't care about the table and database.... because the function that means get mayny row in table `x_giolam` have the atribute `giolam` and sum it...and then we have the salary of a staff.

Comment: Did you mean `tong += i[1]` instead of `tong+=kq[1]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the query is "select name,giolam ...", kq probably is something like:

```
[ ('Thong', 324.34), ('Tran', 543.34), ('Thang', 765.52) ... ]
```

So I think you want:

```
for record in kq:
    tong+=record[1]
```

Instead of `tong+=kq[1]`.